# Unexpectable result of `zip` usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have two arrays. First is array of objects from DB `@groups = Group.where(blabla)`. Second comes from API request `response = [false, false, something]`. When I try to go through both of them:

```
@groups.zip(response).each do |group, r|
.
.
end
```

`@groups` array starts from second element and puts first in the last iteration. Why it happens?
With `yi = @groups.pluck(:id)` I can see that the order of the array is proper!

To be more clear I expect `result  = [[403, false], [404, false], [405, something]]` , but I have `result  = [[404, false], [405, false], [403, something]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, the problem has nothing to do with ruby, it is DB engine issue. `Group.where(blabla)` is basically executed as `SELECT * FROM groups WHERE blabla`. Unless one have explicitly specified the `order` of this query, the result set order **is not guaranteed**.

`pluck` is translated to slightly different query, and DB engine might return the result set in the different order.

Use explicit [ordering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) in your queries to retrieve the results in the specific order.

Comment: But I use pluck on selection! I don't think that pluck reorder something.

Comment: Would you mind to read my answer carefully? [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) generates _another SQL query_. “use pluck on selection” makes no sense, `pluck` is used by Rails _before_ the SQL query is even being sent to DB engine. Different queries might return results in different order. That’s it. **Nobody guarantees that the order of record set returned is defined unless explicit `ORDER BY` clause is specified in SQL query**.

Comment: I'm sure you are right and this time is more understandable for me. Thanks